# Как убрать перезагрузку страницы, по нажатию на button?

Tags: javascript, dom

Всем привет! У меня есть маленькая форма для входа на страницу.

```
<section class="section">
        <div class="auth">
            <div class="auth-header">
                <img src="assets/logo_vk.png" alt="" class="logo">
                <h1>Вход</h1>
                <a href="registration.html" class="registration">Регистрация</a>
            </div>
            <div class="auth-main">
                <form action="">
                    <label><input name="login" type="text" class="login" placeholder="Телефон или email" autocomplete="off"></label>
                    <label><input name="password" type="password" class="password" placeholder="Пароль" autocomplete="off"></label>
                    <button class="auth-button">Войти</button>
                    <div class="password-forgot-block">
                        <a href="#" class="password-forgot">Забыли пароль?</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

И я хочу добавить такой скрипт. Если input-ы пустые, то сделать background данного инпута красным цветом.

```
.background-color {
    background-color: #faebd7;
} 

let login = document.querySelector('.login');
let password = document.querySelector('.password');
let btnLogin = document.querySelector('.auth-button');


btnLogin.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (login.value === '' && password.value === '') {
        login.classList.add('background-color');
        password.classList.add('background-color');
    } else if (login.value === '' && password.value !== '') {
        login.classList.add('background-color');
    } else if (login.value !== '' && password.value === '') {
        password.classList.add('background-color');
    }
});
```

Но возникает странная ошибка или не знаю что, вообщем если я заполняю одно поле и хочу проверить другие условия, когда я нажимаю на button, страница перезагружается. Все инпуты обнуляются. Почему так происходит не понятно. Есть кто разбирается, как это можно решить?

Comment: Похоже, что срабатывает submit при нажатии на button.

Comment: А вообще, вам не на кнопку, которая отправляет данные формы для обработки надо вешать подобную проверку, а на событие change или даже keyup самих элементов input. В этом случае ещё до отправки формы вы сможете проверить - заполнены ли обязательные поля и если нет, подкрасить их фон красным цветом. Ну и при создании формы, пока инпуты пустые - тоже самое сделать. А кнопка пусть занимается своим делом.

Comment: можно поставить атрибут required у нужных инпутов

Comment: Почитай что такое preventDefaul
В нем кроется ответ на твой недуг https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 3):

```js
    let login = document.querySelector('.login');
    let password = document.querySelector('.password');
    let btnLogin = document.querySelector('.auth-button');

    btnLogin.addEventListener('click', function () {
        event.preventDefault(); // Убираем событие отправки формы
        if (login.value === '' && password.value === '') {
            login.classList.add('background-color');
            password.classList.add('background-color');
        } else if (login.value === '' && password.value !== '') {
            login.classList.add('background-color');
        } else if (login.value !== '' && password.value === '') {
            password.classList.add('background-color');
        } else {
            // Вызываете обработчик формы
            document.getElementById('fform').submit();
        }
    });
```

```css
    .background-color {
        background-color: #faebd7;
    }
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="auth">
        <div class="auth-header">
            <img src="assets/logo_vk.png" alt="" class="logo">
            <h1>Вход</h1>
            <a href="registration.html" class="registration">Регистрация</a>
        </div>
        <div class="auth-main">
            <form id="fform" action="">
                <label><input name="login" type="text" class="login" placeholder="Телефон или email" autocomplete="off"></label>
                <label><input name="password" type="password" class="password" placeholder="Пароль" autocomplete="off"></label>
                <button class="auth-button">Войти</button>
                <div class="password-forgot-block">
                    <a href="#" class="password-forgot">Забыли пароль?</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Разве event не надо указать, как аргумент функции?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что при нажатии активного элемента(ссылка, кнопки отправки формы) выполняется действие элемента по умолчанию. Чтобы этого не происходило, надо это действие предотвращать, например, с помощью [preventDefault()](https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action).

```
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', function (e) {//e - событие элемента по умолчанию
    login.classList.remove('background-color');
    password.classList.remove('background-color');
    if (login.value === '') {
        login.classList.add('background-color');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (password.value === '') {
        password.classList.add('background-color');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: А отправлять форму пользователь как будет?

Comment: Ваша правда, невнимательно прочитал вопрос, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант переписать JS-функцию так:

```js
btnLogin.onclick = function () {
 if (login.value === '' && password.value === '') {
  login.classList.add('background-color');
  password.classList.add('background-color');
  return false;
 } else if (login.value === '' && password.value !== '') {
  login.classList.add('background-color');
  return false;
 } else if (login.value !== '' && password.value === '') {
  password.classList.add('background-color');
  return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
</form>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]